# Second external monitor does not work via USB-C to HDMI adapter

Tags: nvidia, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I'm using *Xubuntu 21.10*. I have an *ASUS Zephyrus G14* laptop with two video cards. One integrated on the *AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX* CPU and another one *Nvidia RTX-3060*. I have an external monitor connected to the HDMI port. I connected a second external monitor via a USB-C to an HDMI adapter. I have dual boot with *Windows 11* and the setup works on *Windows*. But the *Ubuntu* cannot detect the second external monitor. Initially, the setup was not working even on *Windows* but it started to work after a while. I suspect that this is because *Windows* downloaded some drivers in the background. I tried with both the latest *Nvidia* driver available via the *Additional Drivers* menu and with the open-source drivers for the video card, but it is not working in both way. Does someone know how to make the second external monitor work?

Comment: When you tried the Nvidia drivers did you used mokutil to enable them with Secure Boot (required for Windows 11) and used the Nvidia X Server Settings app/tool to enable Nvidia instead of the iGPU? If either of this conditions wasn't met then it not working with the external monitor is to be expected. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not sure. Could you explain which are the steps to do it the right way?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bitsurgeon/b0f4440984c9e60dcd8fe8bbc346c029 or, even better, https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-ubuntu-18-04.html

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I have secure boot enabled and I choose Nvidia in the Nvidia X Server Settings. The result is the same.

Comment: @ChanganAuto
> If either of this conditions wasn't met then it not working with the external monitor is to be expected.

Do you understand that I already have one external monitor working? I'm trying to connect a second one via HDMI to a USB-C adapter.